# Reading Xml element value and display it in Textbox control using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a sample.xml file like this:

'root element

   'FilePath element
   
      'FilePath element value
       C:\Users\Desktop

I need to read the FilePath value, that is "C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto" and display it in textBox1 control. If possible code snippets in VB.net please

Any suggestions please?

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make:

```
Dim filePath as String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "sample.xml")
Dim xml as XElement = XElement.Load(filePath)
textBox1.Text = xml.ToString()
```

Comment: sorry mate, I coded in this way  Dim xmlDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
        Dim node As System.Xml.XmlNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
        xmlDoc.Load(fullPath + "\configfile.xml")   textbox1.Text = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("FilePath").Value     but it is not working. I am not sure what am i missing.It is displaying blank in textbox

Comment: You should edit your question with some more data, like a sample of the full XML and what is the output you are expecting.